# Print a number converted in base 2 recursively

Tags: c, radix

So I've been trying to do this but I just can't think of a solution for this. I've got this bit of code but it outputs it backwards(if the answer is 11110 I get 01111):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int base(int n)
{
    if(n==0)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        printf("%d",n%2);
    }
    return base(n/2);


}
int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    base(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any trick for this problem or do I need to analyze this deeper?

Comment: Rather than printing the digits in the order they're processed (right to left), pass a buffer around where you can fill in those digits in the correct order. Then print at the end.

Comment: Print after the recursive call, not before.

Comment: I would use a mask in order to avoid having a buffer, see my answer

Comment: Rares Amza, What should print when `n < 0`? When `n== 0`?

Comment: thanks for the useful tips, also the one with printing after the call will be very useful
@chux-ReinstateMonica I didn't really care about the case when ```n<0```, and when ```n==0``` it should print just ```0``` I guess since that is how you represent it in base 2

Comment: @RaresAmza With "I didn't really care about the case when n<0, and when n==0 it should print just 0", accepted answer `base(-11)` as `"-10-1-1"` is OK and  `base(0)` prints nothing. Interesting.  UV for explaining your goals yet disagree with them.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I will revisit this soon to try and make it work 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@rici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici) stated, a very simple fix is to print after the recursive call:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void base(int n){
    if(n==0)
        return;
    base(n/2);
    printf("%d",n%2);
}

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    base(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what about the line return?

Comment: mm I guess a simple wrapper could fix that!

Comment: Note: `base(0)` prints nothing.

Comment: `base(-7)` prints "-1-1-1"

Answer (score -2):

I would use a mask:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int base(int n, int mask){
    if(!mask) {
        printf("\n"); // we reach the end, print a line return
        return 0;
    }
    printf("%d",  !!(n & mask)); // if mask and n match, print '1', else print '0'. !! convert any value into 1, and 0 remains 0.
    return base(n, mask >> 1); // divide mask by 2, check the next bit on the right
}

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    base(n, 1 << (31 - __builtin_clz(n))); // call the function with a mask initialized at the same level than the most important bit of n. 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `__builtin_clz(n)` is not part of C.  This answer assumes select compilers and `int` range.  A shift of `1 << 31` is a problem too.